# Remove the blank row values in chart

Tags: vba, excel

I am generating a chart from table. the table rows are not completely filled.

so when I am generating an chart, I get the value of not filled columns also as "0". I would like to remove the "0" (value of blank rows") in my chart. Is
there a way I can do this? any lead would be helpful

```
Sub chartResult()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:D53")
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").ChartObjects.delete
 Set sh = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=440, _
    Width:=600, _
    Top:=340, _
    Height:=250)
 sh.Select
 Set cht = ActiveChart
With cht
 .SetSourceData Source:=rng
 .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
End With
 cht.SeriesCollection(1).name = "Ov"
 cht.SeriesCollection(2).name = "O"
 cht.SeriesCollection(3).name = "To"

 cht.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True
 cht.SeriesCollection(2).HasDataLabels = True
 cht.SeriesCollection(3).HasDataLabels = True
 cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(72, 118, 255)  '<~~ Red
 cht.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
 cht.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 167, 0)
 cht.HasTitle = True
 cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Result "
End Sub
```

[image: this is the sample image of my graph. I would like to remove all the zero values.IS there a way could do]

Comment: You wan't to remove just the `0` as in the label or you want to remove it completely like it never exist?

Comment: I just want to completely remove them.. anything on such a way that .  It doesnot exist in my chart anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try the property `Chart.DisplayBlanksAs` and set `xlNotPlotted`.

So in the code the change looks some what as shown below in `with` statement.

```
With cht
 .SetSourceData Source:=rng
 .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
 .DisplayBlanksAs = xlNotPlotted  //ADD THIS STAEMENT.
End With
```

Comment: still it I could see the same graph

Comment: when I am debugging, I et the  xlnotplotted as 1

Comment: @Jenny.... Look into this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xldisplayblanksas-enumeration-excel

Answer (score 0):

@Jenny - I can't guarantee this will work, I don't work with charts, but give it a try.

```
With cht
 .SetSourceData Source:=rng
 .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
 .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
End With
```